# Accessing a file from IPython working directory

Tags: python, ipython

I am new to IPython but not new to Python, in Python IDE you just copy the file into the project directory to work with it, in IPython I can't access it even if it is in the directory of IPython

```
import os

os.getcwd()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\Adham'

import scipy as sp

data = sp.genfromtxt("web_traffic.tsv", delimiter="\t")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e833c1c1a7bc> in <module>()
----> 1 data = sp.genfromtxt("web_traffic.tsv", delimiter="\t")

C:\Users\Adham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skiprows, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise)
   1364                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
   1365             else:
-> 1366                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rb'))
   1367             own_fhd = True
   1368         else:

C:\Users\Adham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(path, mode, destpath)
    149 
    150     ds = DataSource(destpath)
--> 151     return ds.open(path, mode)
    152 
    153 

C:\Users\Adham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(self, path, mode)
    499             return _file_openers[ext](found, mode=mode)
    500         else:
--> 501             raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
    502 
    503 

OSError: web_traffic.tsv not found.
```

Note: I used the Anaconda Installer 3.4 64bit 
and my web_traffic.tsv is in c:\users\Adham

Answer (score 0):

Since this is IPython, type `ls`. Do you see the file there? If it is, then perhaps you made a typo? If not, the file is not in your working directory.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct it is s typo, file's extension was .tsv.csv instead of .tsv

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the directory that your file is in the sys.path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\[PATH TO DIRECTORY]")
```

Then you can import any file, say file1.txt, in this directory using:

```
data = sp.genfromtxt("file1.tsv", delimiter="\t")
```